# I need a sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, list, sorting, data-structures, ranking

I'm looking for an algrorithm.

Given N Users.
Each N Users submits 1 ranked list of Q options out of Z (Z > Q).
Each user's Q options is different.

This could be applied to fruit.
N Users Rankings.

```
[passion fruit, apple, orange, pear, cherry, blueberry, banana]
[blueberry, pear, cherry, banana]
[passion fruit, blueberry, banana, apple, orange]
```

.... ETC

I also want it to be able to be updated upon each new entry.
What is your smartest or best or most efficient solution, specify, and state why? 
THANK YOU SO MUCH IN ADVANCE.

EDIT:
In response to comment, I made an example with fruit. I want a fruit ranking site. Users can come to the site, rank all the types of fruit she or he has tried, and that is there "vote" of rankings. A master list displays the overall ranking. So I guess people's favorite tasting fruit*. The algorithm could work for anything though.

Comment: You forgot to mention what you're actually trying to calculate or what this has to do with sorting. All your question says is that you need to input some data, which doesn't require any algorithm other than a simple loop.

Comment: I made an example with fruit. I want a fruit ranking site. Users can come to the site, rank all the types of fruit she or he has tried, and that is there "vote" of rankings. A master list displays the overall ranking. So I guess people's favorite tasting fruit*. The algorithm could work for anything though.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is store an average rank to each fruit and the final overall ranking list can be sorted by the average rank of fruits. For the examples you gave, `passion fruit` is ranked 0 twice, thus would have average rank of 0. `blueberry` is ranked 5, 0, and 1 in three entries, thus would have average rank of 2. The final overall ranking list would start with `passion fruit` and other fruits sorted by average ranks.

```
Map<String, int[]> fruitToRank = new HashMap<String, int[]>();
//key is name of the fruit
//val[0] is sum of ranks and val[1] is vote counts for the fruit

void newEntry(String[] rank) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rank.length; i++) {
        String fruitName = rank[i];

        if (fruitToRank.containsKey(fruitName)) {
            int[] rankInfo = fruitToRank.get(fruitName);
            rankInfo[0] += i; //add rank to sum of ranks
            rankInfo[1]++; //number of vote counts
        } else {
            int[] rankInfo = new int[] {i, 1};
            fruiteToRank.put(fruitName, rankInfo);
    }
}

int[] getNFavoriteFruits(int n) {
    int[] result = new int[n];

    //fruit with lower number as average rank has higher priority
    PriorityQueue<String> pq = new PriorityQueue<String>((s1, s2) -> {
        int[] rankInfo1 = fruitToRank.get(s1);
        int[] rankInfo2 = fruitToRank.get(s2);

        double averageRank1 = (double)rankInfo1[0] / rankInfo1[1];
        double averageRank2 = (double)rankInfo2[0] / rankInfo2[1];

        return averageRank1 - averageRank2;
    });

    for (String k: fruitToRank.keySet()) {
        pq.add(k);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        result[i] = pq.poll();
    }
    return result;
}
```